# regex backtracking to value within match

Tags: regex

I have this regex

```
(\w*):([0-9]*).*\1:-([0-9]*)
```

that matches the following string

```
start foo:100 xxxxx bar:300 yyyyy bar:-600 jjjjjj foo:-200 end
```

giving me 3 groups

```
foo
100
200
```

How do I change the regex so I get 2 matches like

```
foo
100
200

bar
300
600
```

Comment: What **language** are you doing this in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put your regex inside a positive lookahead assertion so that it would do an overlapping match.

```
(?=\b(\w+)\b:([0-9]+).*\1:-([0-9]*))
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/jE8sO0/1)

Answer (score 1):

```
(\w*):([0-9]+)(?=.*\1:-([0-9]*))
```

Try this.Once you capture or move ahead the regex engine wont backtrack.So you can capture the first part and put the rest in lookahead and capture there.This way engine will just make an assertion that there is a similar group ahead but it wont move ahead.

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/bW3aR1/13